# Android Snackbar setAction displaying button with text instead just text

Tags: java, android, android-snackbar

I need to create a Snackbar, with text, when I click on it, the Snackbar will close. But instead of text, the action button is rendered as a button with my action text. I've never seen such a problem anywhere. The version of android.support.design v7: 25.3.1. Min API version is 16.

```
Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(v_osnov, Html.fromHtml("
<fontcolor=\"#ffffff\">Tag deleted</font>") , Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE); 
    
snackbar.setDuration(5000);

snackbar.setAction("Dismiss", new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

    }
  });
snackbar.show();
```

This is what I am getting instead of just action text:

[image]

Comment: Having to use HTML to make the text white already is a bad sign. That should be automatic - white text on dark background. ***///*** What's `v_osnov`? Did you extend `AppCompatActivity`? Do you use an AppCompat or Design theme? Did you at any point use `getApplicationContext()` to inflate views?

Comment: I am using HTML because the default text color is dark, not white. v_osnov is an xml resourse file, wich is a part of MainActivity. Also, class where Snackbar is implemented is not an Activity. I am using AppCompat theme

Comment: My point is *the text is supposed to be white by default*. You shouldn't have to set it to white, that's not a solution. Remove the HTML. The button looks like from Android 2 theme. It shouldn't. The whole Snackbar uses bad theme. ***///*** Please add to your question code *how you got `v_osnov`* and where did you get the Context.

Comment: View v_osnov=cma.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.edt_osnov,null); - where "cma" is the object of MainActivity

Comment: Let's debug. Does it work correctly if you write `Snackbar.make(activity.findViewById(android.R.id.content), "Tag deleted", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)` instead?

Comment: Yes, now it is no button on snackbar, just action text. But color of main text is still black.

Comment: Are you sure your activity extends AppCompatActivity? Snackbar uses android:theme attribute to set its theme to dark but it looks like it's ignored. That happens in activities that can't interpret the theme attribute - activities that don't extend AppCompatActivity.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than trying to get your colour from HTML, you should rather use the below method if you want to change the action's text colour

```
Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(...)
    .setDuration(...)
    .setAction(...)
    //Note the method call beneath
    .setActionTextColor(R.color.white);
```

This way, you would get the desired text without the surrounding area of colour